# Solving for 3 Variables using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I've had experience in the past with Lagrange multipliers, but am struggling with this one.

> Maximize $f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) = \sqrt{x_{1}x_{2}} + \sqrt{x_{3}}$ *subject to the constraint* $p_{1}x_{1} + p_{2}x_{2} + p_{3}x_{3} = m$, where $p_{i}$ is a constant $\geq 0$  *and* $x_{i} \geq 0$

I've done the beginning, with ease :

$$\frac{x_{2}}{2\sqrt{x_{1}x_{2}}} = \lambda p_{1} $$

$$\frac{x_{1}}{2\sqrt{x_{1}x_{2}}} = \lambda p_{2} $$

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_{3}}} = \lambda p_{3} $$

I notice that if I divide the first equation by the second, and then vice versa, I get:

$$x_{2} = \frac{p_{1}x_{1}}{p_{2}}$$ 
and
$$x_{1} = \frac{p_{2}x_{2}}{p_{1}}$$

However, I can't figure out how to proceed/what to do with the third equation. I find myself often going in circles/getting unreasonable answers with Lagrange multipliers. Any advice would be great here, thanks!

Comment: Hint:  The first two equations tell you that $\lambda^2 = \frac {1}{4p_1p_2}$.  You can square the third equation and use this.

Comment: Are there other constraints, like $x_3 \ge 0$, $x_1 x_2 \ge 0$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, I'll update it. Thanks

Comment: I presume you must have $p_k >0$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, this is actually an economic-style question where $p_{i}$ represents the price of good $x_{i}$

Comment: Before you can use Lagrange multipliers you need to establish that the constraints $x_k \ge 0$ are not active.

Comment: @copper.hat The question said nothing about this but given its context I'd assume that $x_{k} \geq 0$ are not active

Comment: If you take $m=p_k = 1$, I think the the unique maximiser is $(0,0,1)$. (It may still be OK to ignore the positivity constraints, but it is not immediate it me.)

Comment: @lulu I've been working to try to see how you got this equivalency but am failing - would you mind elaborating

Comment: First equation becomes $\sqrt{\frac {x_1}{x_2}}=2\lambda p_1$.  Second becomes $\sqrt{\frac {x_2}{x_1}}=2\lambda p_2$ whence $2\lambda p_1= \frac {1}{2\lambda p_2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that some care must be taken here when applying the Lagrange multiplier method as the cost function is not differentiable at all feasible points.

I am assuming that $p_k >0$ for all $k$, and (implicitly) that $m>0$.

Note that the feasible set is compact, hence a minimiser and a maximiser exist. Not that it matters here, but the minimum is seen to be zero and must have $x_3=0$ and either $x_1$ or $x_2$ equal to zero (in which case the constraint gives the value of $x_2,x_1$ respectively).

Suppose $x$ is a maximiser, then either at least one component is zero or none are zero. If none are zero, the Lagrange condition **must** hold.

Suppose $x$ is a maximiser and $x_3 = 0$. Consider a perturbation
$z(t) = x+(-{p_3 \over 2 p_1} t^2, -{p_3 \over 2 p_2} t^2, t^2)$ for
small $t$. The
choice of $t^2$ is to ensure that the cost $d(t) = f(z(t))$ is differentiable at $t=0$. It is easy to check that $z(t)$ is feasible for small $t$. It is also easy to verify that $d'(0) = 1 >0$, and so we
see that $x=d(0)$ is **not** a maximiser. Hence we know that if $x$ is
a maximiser, then $x_3 >0$.

Now suppose $x$ is a maximiser with $x_k >0$ for all $k$. The Lagrange condition must hold.

Multiplying the first two equations together gives ${1 \over 4} =  \lambda^2 p_1 p_2$, the third gives
$\sqrt{x_3} = {1 \over 2 \lambda p_3}$. Hence $\lambda >0$ and so $\lambda = {1 \over 2 \sqrt{p_1 p_2}}$, which gives $x_3 = { p_1 p_2 \over p_3^2 }$.
The equations give $\lambda p_1 x_1 = \lambda p_2 x_2 = {1 \over 2 } \sqrt{x_1 x_2}$, hence $p_1 x_1 = p_2 x_2$. The constraint gives
$2 p_1 x_1 = m - p_3 x_3 = m - {p_1 p_2 \over p_3 }$. Since $x_1 >0$, we have $m > {p_1 p_2 \over p_3 }$. In this case, the
cost is given by ${1 \over 2} {m - {p_1 p_2 \over p_3} \over \sqrt{p_1 p_2} } + { \sqrt{p_1 p_2 } \over p_3}$.

Note, in particular, that if $m \le {p_1 p_2 \over p_3 }$, this condition
implies that the Lagrange condition cannot hold, hence in this case, at
least one of $x_1,x_2$ must be zero. In this case, the cost is given
by $\sqrt{x_3}$, and hence is maximised when $x_3 = {m \over p_3}$ with
cost $\sqrt{m \over p_3}$.

Combining these, we see that the maximum cost is given by
${1 \over 2} {\max(m - {p_1 p_2 \over p_3},0) \over \sqrt{p_1 p_2} } + \min({ \sqrt{p_1 p_2 } \over p_3}, \sqrt{m \over p_3})$.

---

Here is a slightly simpler approach:

Note that the constraints imply that $x_3 \in [0,{ m \over p_3}]$.
Fix $x_3$ and solve the problem $\min \{x_1 x_2 | p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 = m-p_3 x_3 \}$. The Lagrange conditions are $x_2 = \mu p_1, x_1 = \mu p_2$, which gives $\mu = {m-p_3 x_3 \over 2 p_1 p_2 }$. Substituting values
shows that the original cost is
$c(x_3) = {m-p_3 x_3 \over 2 \sqrt{p_1 p_2 }} + \sqrt{x_3}$.
It is straightforward to see that this is strictly increasing up to a maximum (for $x_3 \ge 0$) at $x_3^* = {\sqrt{p_2 p_2} \over p_3}$, and then strictly decreasing afterwards.

In particular, the maximiser of the original problem is $\hat{x}_3 = \min({{p_2 p_2} \over p_3^2}, {m \over p_3})$, computing
$c(\hat{x}_3)$ results in the expression above.

Comment: Is it not the case that when we multiply the first two equations we obtain $x_{1}x_{2}$ in the numerator and $4x_{1}x_{2}$ in the denominator, in which $x_{1}x_{2}$ would cancel? I'm not seeing how you obtained $\sqrt{x_{1}x_{2}}$. Thank you

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. Will try to fix in a while.

Comment: @JonathanWu: I fixed my solution (which was incorrect). The solution depends on $m,p_1,p_2,p_3$ in a non smooth manner.